# In Javascript, how do I check if string is only letters+numbers (underscore allowed)?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I check that?

I want to allow all A-Za-z0-9 , and underscore.  Any other symbol, the function should return false.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
function isValid(str) { return /^\w+$/.test(str); }
```

`\w` is a character class that represents exactly what you want: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. If you want the empty string to return `true`, change the `+` to a `*`.

To help you remember it, the `\w` is a `w`ord character. (It turns out that words have underscores in JavaScript land.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a solution:

```
function check(input) {
  return /^\w+$/i.test(input);
}
```