# JavaScript & regex : How do I check if the string is ASCII only?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know I can validate against string with words ( 0-9 A-Z a-z and underscore ) by applying `W` in regex like this:

```
function isValid(str) { return /^\w+$/.test(str); }
```

But how do I check whether the string contains ASCII characters only? ( I think I'm close, but what did I miss? )

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8253200/188331

**UPDATE** : Standard character set is enough for my case.

Comment: What's wrong with current solution?

Comment: Standard or extended character set?

Comment: I want ASCII symbols such as parenthesis , hyphen , question marks , fullstop to be included.

Comment: standard character set is enough for this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex any ascii character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203190/regex-any-ascii-character)

Comment: I will disagre with @sachleen if only because the linked question does not specify the language that the regex is implemented in. It can make a big difference. For example, [the feature described in this answer is not valid in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3203258/497418).

Comment: @zzzzBov and there are other answers that do work in JS.

Comment: @sachleen, while that may be true, generally a question is considered different when it deals with different languages. For example, a question answering what the `+=` operator does in JavaScript is not considered a duplicate of one that answers what the `+=` operator does in C#, even though the same answer may be applicable.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

All you need to do it test that the characters are in the right character range.

```
function isASCII(str) {
    return /^[\x00-\x7F]*$/.test(str);
}
```

Or if you want to possibly use the extended ASCII character set:

```
function isASCII(str, extended) {
    return (extended ? /^[\x00-\xFF]*$/ : /^[\x00-\x7F]*$/).test(str);
}
```

Comment: @zerkms, between the two of us we'll get there. For now I'll assume `*` as a string of `''` is technically ASCII.

Comment: I'm not insisting on `+` instead of `*`. When I posted my comment there were none of them.

Comment: The extended option does not seem to cover the following characters:
["€", "‚", "ƒ", "„", "…", "†", "‡", "ˆ", "‰", "Š", "‹", "Œ", "Ž", "‘", "’", "“", "”", "•", "–", "—", "˜", "™", "š", "›", "œ", "ž"]

All apart of the extended ASCII character set. As listed here: http://web.itu.edu.tr/~sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html

Comment: @SimonHawesome, your source is bad. The [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) has a reference table in an image at least.

Comment: For the true one liner: `const isASCII = string => /^[\x00-\x7F]*$/.test(string);`.

Comment: For **printable** ASCII: `const isPrintableASCII = string => /^[\x20-\x7F]*$/.test(string);`.

Comment: @K_'s regex allows the DEL character; use `/^[\x20-\x7E]*$/` to disallow it.

Comment: why is it returning true for `isPrintableASCII("0x2")`?

Comment: @ClementWalter, `0`, `x`, and `2` are printable ascii characters. You didn't use a Unicode escape sequence.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need a RegEx to do it, just check if all characters in that string have a char code between 0 and 127:

```
function isValid(str){
    if(typeof(str)!=='string'){
        return false;
    }
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if(str.charCodeAt(i)>127){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: "You don't need a RegEx to do it" --- why not use regex - it will be a trivial one liner

Comment: If he wants "ASCII only" I guess it's >127, not >255

Comment: RegExp is also significantly faster than this version.  This is like 5x slower.

Comment: For any kind of user input < 1k chars (will differ per machine) or so it will not matter if you use a `RegExp` vs this method. It can be done slightly cleaner if you strip the `typeof` check and simply `str.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)).every(c => c <= 127);` Trying to read the code later and decode the regex will be more difficult than understanding the `split(...).map(...)` example, especially when using escapes such as `\x[HEX_VALUE]`. -- Of course, this will not apply when performance **really** matters.

Answer (score 10):

For ES2018, Regexp support [Unicode property escapes](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes), you can use `/[\p{ASCII}]+/u` to match the ASCII characters. It's much clear now.

Supported browsers:

- Chrome 64+
- Safari/JavaScriptCore beginning in Safari Technology Preview 42

Answer (score 2):

```
var check = function(checkString) {

    var invalidCharsFound = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < checkString.length; i++) {
        var charValue = checkString.charCodeAt(i);

        /**
         * do not accept characters over 127
         **/

        if (charValue > 127) {
            invalidCharsFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return invalidCharsFound;
};
```