# Using ASCII Regex with HTML Input pattern

Tags: html, regex

Following [JavaScript & regex : How do I check if the string is ASCII only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313183/javascript-regex-how-do-i-check-if-the-string-is-ascii-only)
how do I use the ASCII-only regex (/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/) in pattern attribute in HTML?
I wish to restrict the user input to only ASCII characters.

```
<form class="row" name="marketDetails">
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-12 form-sm" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"
                               value=""
                               maxlength="50"
                               pattern="[\x00-\x7F]"
                               ng-model="vm.marketMetaData.market_name" required/>
</form
```

Using pattern="[\x00-\x7F]" still lets me use non-ASCII character (e.g ¶) without any error in the form

Thanks.

Comment: Use `pattern="[\x00-\x7F]+"`. It won't let users *submit* invalid input.

Comment: Please add full example, and what framework you are using ?

Comment: I'm afraid the OP was looking for pattern="[\x20-\x7F]+" to exclude control codes.

Answer (score 3):

Use pattern="[\x00-\x7F]+" - that did the trick. thanks!
by Wiktor Stribiżew